# Jquery confirm form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascipt/jquery, and i couldnt find a way to confirm a form submission with a select form that submits "onchange".

When the user selects a new time, i want there to be an alert that says, "Changing the time will empty your cart, do you wish to continue?"

The user can then choose to "cancel" the change or confirm.

```
    <form id="hour_select" action="" method="POST" name="hour_form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="hour" onchange='hour_form.submit()'>
            <option {{selected1900}} value="1900">7:00 PM</option>
            <option {{selected2000}} value="2000">8:00 PM</option>
            <option {{selected2100}} value="2100">9:00 PM</option>
            <option {{selected2200}} value="2200">10:00 PM</option>
            <option {{selected2300}} value="2300">11:00 PM</option>
            <option {{selected2400}} value="2400">12:00 AM</option>
            <option {{selected100}} value="100">1:00 AM</option>
            <option {{selected200}} value="200">2:00 AM</option>
        </select>

        <input type="hidden" name="submit=" value="hour_change"/>

    </form>
```

Comment: Do NOT call anything submit if you want to call the submit hander of the form. Rename the submit button or remove the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code like this so it will bind the event on load:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('select[name=hour]').change(function(){
         if(confirm('Changing the time will empty your cart, do you wish to continue?')){
             $('#hour_select').submit();
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: I think this is a nicer way since it uses jQuery's .change() event, which is the same as .on('change',....), but cleaner codewise...

Comment: lets say i changed the time from 7pm to 9pm. even if i "cancel" the change, the select button still shows 9pm. is there a way to change this?

Comment: save the value to a hidden field everytime you change. Then on the `if(confirm(....))` put an `else` clause and on that else you check if the value is different than what was previously set... if it is, change it back to it's original value.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `onchange` attribute you can use jQuery `on` method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select[name=hour]').on('change', function() {
     if (confirm("Changing the time will ....")) {
         $('#hour_select').submit()   
     } else {
         $('option:first', this).prop('selected', true)
     }
  })
})
```

Also note that you should put your code inside document ready handler.

Comment: lets say i changed the time from 7pm to 9pm. even if i "cancel" the change, the select button still shows 9pm. is there a way to change this?

Comment: @anc1revv Sorry, I don't get you, when you cancel the cinfirm and change the value of select element, you see the previous value?

Comment: @mplungjan There is an error in your code, yes, I think he wants to select the first option upon cancel.

Comment: It is late here.  Interesting version with the prop. Will select the first no matter what. I like

Comment: no i meant, upon cancel, i want to return to whatever time he had selected.  it's not always going to be 7pm

Comment: Ah. save the current selection in a cookie upon submit unless the target of the form is another window or frame

Answer (score -1):

```
$('select[name=hour]').on('change', function(){
    var conf = confirm('Changing the time will empty your cart, do you wish to continue?');
    if(conf == true){
        hour_form.submit();
    }else{
        //do nothing, right?
    }
});
```

Comment: You are missing a $("#hour_select") there. Not all browser will allow your way of accessing the form

Comment: @mplungjan you're right, netscape navigator 4 won't. Am I worried about netscape navigator 4?

Comment: Very poor argument and it is a lot more browsers

Comment: No need. Just because you cannot be bothered to type a few more chars and be compatible. It is called defensive coding. Just do it. It does not hurt and it can save a LOT of debugging